# MemSQL: Leaf error: timed out from socket after -1 seconds

Tags: timeout, singlestore, columnstore

We are running a 4 node cluster currently, (3 machines with 8GB and one with 4GB RAM) and while trying run a left outer join of a table (about 7.5 GB) on itself. Few of the fields of the table have been stored as columnstore.
The structure of the query is somewhat like:

```
SELECT a.x, a.y from tableX left outer join tableY on a.z=b.z group by a.x;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We've seen this error reproduce when the machine is under a significant amount of load (it triggers an internal TCP timeout, hence the -1 as it's not one of ours).

Were the machines running with a lot of load while you ran the query? E.g. you were running several other queries concurrently or something else on the machines?

We are actively working on resolving this in a general way (it is relatively hard to reproduce), and we will keep this thread up-to-date with our progress.

Comment: No, just under load from the query.. the 4GB m/c is the master aggregator, and the remaining 8GB nodes are leaves. The tables has some fields as columnstore and the query runs a substring operation on a shard key field (the shard key composes of two fields..) , along with right outer join of the table on itself, and a group by on a shard key field.    Should I do something about my schema or query to make this work on MemSQL?